# Winning as white is a struggle!

Tags: analysis, endgame

```
[Title "White to move"]
[FEN "5r2/5q1k/6pp/1p2P3/1P2p2P/6RK/3Q1P2/8 w KQkq - 0 1"]
```

I can’t seem to win here, no matter what I do. Is the position really that bad for me as White?

Comment: Is it white or black to move?

Comment: Why should you win by force here? What advantage(s) do you have?

Comment: I can't seem to find any advantages. I find I'm always on the defensive and don't have many options to attack/check/threaten etc.. Any thoughts?

Comment: Not expecting an easy win, just wondering if any more experienced players can see a way to win. Good learning curve

Answer (score 3):

The position is roughly equal. The problem for both sides, but it is a little worse for white, is king safety. That is the overwhelming positional factor here.

Kg2 and Qd4 is the best plan for white here to counter the threat on f2. It is positionally mutually difficult to do anything since both queens and rooks must keep defending soft spots. Trying to do more, and you likely get mated.

Here is a short sample line with notes.

```
 [FEN "5r2/5q1k/6pp/1p2P3/1P2p2P/6RK/3Q1P2/8 w - - 0 1"]


 1. Kg2 {to defend f2} Qf5 {activating the queen a little} 2. Qd4 {also activating the queen a little, but keeping an eye on f2 at the same time} Rf7 3. Qb6 {keeping black thinking about the white queen taking on g6 and then mate} Kg7 {pass} 4. Kg1 {pass, and not much progress can be made.}
```

Comment: I would be interested in the down-voter's reasoning.

Comment: We all would.  I lost 80 points one day as some schmuck went through and did something to a lot of my posts.  It was not clear who did it, what he did , or why I lost so many points.  Down voting should require reasons and anything that  costs ten points at a time should have very good provable reasons not just that they do not like it.

Comment: I had someone hit me for quite a few downvotes the other day. It was clearly retaliatory for something I am not sure of. I do not care in terms of the points, but I dare most anyone to debate me on position.

Comment: At 9518 I would be less worried:)    But I was just over 300 at the time.  But still annoying when it happens anonymously with no reasons.  I guess some insecure people feel good by being able to do it.  I wont lose any sleep just feel sorry for such people.

Comment: Thanks Phish, that's basically what I encountered. Hard to push a mate without losing myself. I'll keep plugging away!

Comment: @MagicCoconut Glad to help. If you find the answer to be best, and you can actually change your mind if a better answer were to be posted, please feel free to click the check mark, and accept it. We appreciate it for our effort.

Answer (score 1):

move queen to D6 THAT GUARDS F2 DUE TO CM

Answer (score 0):

Yes.  It should be hard for white to win.

Material is even.
No obvious positional advantages.

Why should you have an easy win?

Black is threatening to win a pawn.

You are going to lose at least one pawn but might be able to get some counterplay to hold the draw.

Why do you think white should win at all?

And yes, white's position is bad.

After Kg2 then black plays Qe7 and forks two pawns which should be hard to counter. After Rg2 black can check on f5 and win a pawn.